# Problem with pulling / pushing the stackdriver log to Cloud function

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-stackdriver

Created stackdriver Log sink with cloud pub/sub topic and this topic has been subscribed with below cloud function to print the log message but it throws an error when testing the function.
Before testing the function , produced that error to get the logs in stackdriver logging.

```py
import base64

def hello_pubsub(event, context):
    """Triggered from a message on a Cloud Pub/Sub topic.
    Args:
         event (dict): Event payload.
         context (google.cloud.functions.Context): Metadata for the event.
    """
    pubsub_message = base64.b64decode(event['data']).decode('utf-8')
    print(pubsub_message)
```

The error message I get:

```
Error: function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for termination reason. Details:
'data'
```

But I couldn't find any logs. It only says that the function finished with status 'crash'.

I assume the problem is with pulling / pushing the log to function.
Any help would be appreciated .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue with the Python runtime that is in the process of being resolved: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/155215191